# H2 database compiled into a native-image is only functional as a client

Tags: java, native, h2, quarkus

After build the native image I've the following error 
I'm using a H2 database in file mode.
Do I should understand that it's not possible to use H2 in native mode using a file DB ?

./controler-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner -Dquarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/Dev/controler/sic

quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./sic
quarkus.datasource.driver=org.h2.Driver

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
        at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:473)
        at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:193)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1538)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
        at com.evolis.rpms.sic.controler.StatusBean.checkHostersState(StatusBean.java:100)
        at com.evolis.rpms.sic.controler.StatusBean_Subclass.checkHostersState$$superaccessor6(Unknown Source)
        at com.evolis.rpms.sic.controler.StatusBean_Subclass$$function$$12.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.InvocationContextImpl.interceptorChainCompleted(InvocationContextImpl.java:141)
        at io.quarkus.arc.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:161)
        at io.quarkus.arc.ActivateRequestContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(ActivateRequestContextInterceptor.java:22)
        at io.quarkus.arc.ActivateRequestContextInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.InvocationContextImpl$InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InvocationContextImpl.java:254)
        at io.quarkus.arc.InvocationContextImpl.invokeNext(InvocationContextImpl.java:133)
        at io.quarkus.arc.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:157)
        at com.evolis.rpms.sic.controler.StatusBean_Subclass.checkHostersState(Unknown Source)
        at com.evolis.rpms.sic.controler.StatusBean_ClientProxy.checkHostersState(Unknown Source)
        at com.evolis.rpms.sic.controler.StatusBean_ScheduledInvoker_checkHostersState_68e943c3d502cee246226dbe51d54e7cd7502168.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.scheduler.runtime.QuartzScheduler$InvokerJob.execute(QuartzScheduler.java:249)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1988)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1918)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1896)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:936)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:339)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2693)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2540)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1537)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1561)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1529)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: H2 database compiled into a native-image is only functional as a client: can't create an Embedded Database Session" [50000-197]
        at org.h2.message.TraceObject.logAndConvert(TraceObject.java:357)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:140)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:103)
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:200)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:357)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:346)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: H2 database compiled into a native-image is only functional as a client: can't create an Embedded Database Session
        at org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.isRemote(ConnectionInfo.java:20)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:331)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:124)
        ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at least for now, we don't support running H2 as a server in native mode. The only thing we support is connecting to a remote H2 database using the H2 JDBC client.

It didn't seem like time well spent at the time and, to be honest, I'm not sure we ever will.

If you're interested, feel free to try to get it working but it might not be easy.

Comment: Guillaume, this statement is still valid? I'm making a proof-of-concept application (on https://github.com/FDelporte/JavaQuarkusRestDb) to compare it with a Spring one which is described here https://webtechie.be/post/2020-07-13-spring-rest-h2-raspberry-pi/ but got blocked on this same problem.

Comment: I think, this is required now as lot of java dev is shifting to native.

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported in quarkus.

If you want to run integration tests in native executable, you can add @QuarkusTestResource(H2DatabaseTestResource.class) on any class in your integration tests. The test suite will start and stop the embedded database as a separate process as necessary to run your tests.

Example,

```
import io.quarkus.test.common.QuarkusTestResource;
import io.quarkus.test.h2.H2DatabaseTestResource;

@QuarkusTestResource(H2DatabaseTestResource.class)
public class TestResources {}
```

This allows you to test your application even when it is compiled into a native executable, while the database will run in the JVM as usual.

Connect to it using:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:test
```